# Complete refresh to a materialized view every minute

Tags: oracle, oracle8i

I am creating a mv with the next sentence:

```
create materialized view Vinculaciones_Activas_dos
REFRESH COMPLETE
START WITH (SYSDATE) NEXT (SYSDATE + (1/1440)) WITH ROWID 
as
  select bla,bla,bal
  from bla
```

But I have the problem that it only executes once, I wait for a minute and it doesn't refresh anything.

Comment: What version of Oracle?  What is your `job_queue_processes` parameter set to? Do you see an entry in `DBA_JOBS` for the refresh?

Comment: Do you really intend a complete refresh *every minute*?  I hiope it's a small table!  Why not use an incremental refresh instead?

Comment: The refresh every minute is just an example, the process will going to run once a day. But i'm doing some test to see if it is working

Comment: The version is 8i, how can i see the DBA_JOBS, in this sentence "START WITH (SYSDATE) NEXT (SYSDATE + (1/1440)) WITH ROWID" are not the parameters of the job?

Comment: First, it's always better to specify a numeric version (i.e. 8.1.7.4). "8i" is a marketing label that applies to three major releases and dozens of minor releases. If you are using SQL*Plus, you can see the `job_queue_processes` parameter by typing `SQL> show parameter job_queue_processes`.  You can see whether a job has been created by doing a `SELECT * FROM dba_jobs` and finding the job that is refreshing your materialized view.

Comment: 8i has been out of support for ages now. You should **really** plan your upgrade before doing anything else.